# Extracting specific file names and putting them into the folder of their name

Tags: linux, bash, directory, filenames, mv

I am newby to Bash, Ubuntu 16.04.

I have tons of files, which seems like:

```
aaaa1111
aaaa1112
aaaa1113
aaaa1114 ...

aaab1111
aaab1112
aaab1113
aaab1114 ...

aaac1111 
aaac1112 ... (and so on ...)
```

Anyway, the pattern is 4 characters + and digits. 
All I want to do is making the directory based on the 4 characters, 
and putting the corresponding files into the directory.

for instance,

```
aaaa1111
aaaa1112
aaaa1113
aaaa1114 ...
```

will be put into the directory of aaaa.

```
aaab1111
aaab1112
aaab1113
aaab1114 ...
```

will be put into the directory of aaab.

I tried to 'sed', 'mv', others, but didn't work out well.

Comment: Are all the files in the same directory? There are other files that you want to exclude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for file in [a-z][a-z][a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]; do
    mkdir -p "${file:0:4}" && mv "$file" "${file:0:4}"
done
```

The `for`-loop iterates over the filenames in the current directory with four characters 
and four digits and assigns one filename to variable `file` in each step.

`mkdir` creates the target directory. Using flag `-p` prevents an error message if the directory already exists and `${file:0:4}` leaves the first four characters of the current filename. If the command is successful the file is moved to this directory.

Comment: Good point, thanks! I combined both commands with `&&`. This should make the `mv` safer.

Comment: It it awesome, exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do it:

```
cd your_source_dir || exit

for file in *; do
  if [[ $(echo "$file" | grep -Pw "[a-z]{4}[0-9]{4}") ]]; then
    dir="${file:0:4}"
    [[ -d "$dir" ]] || mkdir "$dir"
    [[ -f "$file"]] && mv "$file" "$dir/"
  fi
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much!